# Authenticate Tableau REST API using Python 2.7

Tags: python, xml, rest, tableau-api, elementtree

I'm having a similar issue to this recently answered question: [Authenticate & Embed Tableau Rest API using python 2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42297545/authenticate-embed-tableau-rest-api-using-python-2-7)

I'm using the same code, but getting a different error. Confirmed that I am calling the correct API version for my Tableau server version.

```
from urllib2 import urlopen, Request
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET # for parsing XML responses
server_name = "http://dashboard.myorg.org"
user_name = "abc"
password = "abc"
site_url_id = ""
signin_url = "{server}/api/2.4/auth/signin".format(server=server_name)
request_xml = ET.Element('tsRequest')
credentials = ET.SubElement(request_xml, 'credentials',
                            name=user_name, password=password)
site_element = ET.SubElement(credentials, 'site',
                             contentUrl=site_url_id)

request_data = ET.tostring(request_xml)

req = Request(signin_url, data=request_data)
req = urlopen(req)

server_response = req.read
response_xml = ET.fromstring(server_response)
token = response_xml.find('.//t:credentials',
                          namespaces={'t': "http://tableau.com/api"}).attrib['token']
site_id = response_xml.find('.//t:site',
                          namespaces={'t': "http://tableau.com/api"}).attrib['id']
print('Sign in successful!')
print('/tToken: {token}'.format(token=token))
print('/tSite ID: {site_id}'.format(site_id=site_id))
headers = {'X-tableau-auth': token}
signout_url = "{server}/api/2.4/auth/signout".format(server=server_name)
req = Request(signout_url, headers=headers, data=b'')
req = urlopen(req)
print('Sign out successful!')
```

My error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "api_call.py", line 20, in <module>
    response_xml = ET.fromstring(server_response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1311, in XML
    parser.feed(text)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1311, in feed
    self._parser.Parse(data, 0)
TypeError: Parse() argument 1 must be string or read-only buffer, not instancemethod
```

Comment: I tried printing the value in server_response, which is the item being identified as an instance method rather than a string. I get the following:

    <bound method _fileobject.read of <socket._fileobject object at 0x02C2A1F0>>

Comment: I think `server_response = req.read` should be `server_response = req.read()`.

Comment: @mzjn That fixed the issue entirely. Thanks! So without the parentheses I was calling the method rather than the string contained by the method?

Comment: Without the parentheses, you were **not** calling the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @mzjn, issue is resolved by updating

```
server_response = req.read
```

to

```
server_response = req.read()
```